# Iterating over a char array inside nested loops

Tags: java, arrays, char, iteration, nested-loops

I'm creating a Hangman game in Java, but I'm having some trouble with the loops I use to compare a letter to a word (char Array):

```
public class Hangman{
  static String seleccionar(){
        //Se selecciona al azar una palabra de la lista
        String[] palabras = {"callado","llamar","esgrima","monedero",
                          "tortuga","semanas","matutino","graduar",
                          "domador","regazo","vicio","carrito",
                          "esqueleto","golosinas","zodiaco","anestesia",
                          "pera","clase","acierto","oliva"};
        int numero = 0;
        numero = (int)(Math.random() * 9);
        String palabra = palabras[numero]; 
        return palabra;
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ahorcado");

        //Método retorna una palabra aleatoria //Method that returns random word
        String palabra = seleccionar();
        System.out.println(palabra);
        char[] letras = palabra.toCharArray();

        //Ocultar la palabra //Hiding the word
        char[] oculto = new char[palabra.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++){
            String underscore = "_"; 
            oculto[i] = underscore.charAt(0);
        }
        
        //Here's the issue

        int contador = 0;
        int s = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < palabra.length(); k++){
            char letraUsuario = sc.next().charAt(0);
            for (char letra: letras){
                if (String.valueOf(letraUsuario).equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(letra)))){
                    oculto[s] = letraUsuario;
                }
                else{
                    contador += 1;
                }
                s += 1;
            }
            for (char letra: oculto){
                System.out.print(letra);
            }
            System.out.println();
            if (contador == 7){
                break;
            }
        }
        sc.close();
}
```

So when I run it, the terminal shows this:

```
Ahorcado
esgrima
r
___r___
m
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 12 out of bounds for length 7
        at Hangman.main(Hangman.java:36)
```

I'm not really sure why it is showing that Index 12, is it iterating more than what I'm telling it to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `s` variable, that you are incrementing (+1 on each loop to get the next letter in the word), but when moving to check against the next `palabra`, you don't reset the `s` back to 0 to start checking from the 0th letter. So the fixed code is easy:

```
int contador = 0;
int s = 0; //SETTING AT 0
for (int k = 0; k < palabra.length(); k++){
    s=0; //RESETTING FOR EACH NEW WORD
    char letraUsuario = sc.next().charAt(0); //ievada simbolu
    for (char letra: letras){
       if (String.valueOf(letraUsuario).equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(letra)))){
          oculto[s] = letraUsuario;
       } else{
          contador += 1;
       }
       s += 1; //this reaches the length of the word at the end of inner loop
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an additional problem in the main loop of your code:

```
for (char letra: letras){
    if (String.valueOf(letraUsuario).equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(letra)))){
        oculto[s] = letraUsuario;
    }
    else{
        contador += 1;
    }
    s += 1;
}
```

contador is being incremented even when the letter is contained within the word, which means for longer words, a single mistake will end the game. It should only be incremented when it hasn't found a matching character after finishing the entire loop.

I recommend you use a Map<Character, List<Integer>> which will record all the characters in the word and their indexes after being selected, which simplifies the main loop as shown here:

```
char[] oculto = new char[palabra.length()];
Map<Character, List<Integer>> characterIndexes = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < oculto.length; i++) {
    oculto[i] = '_';
    if (!characterIndexes.containsKey(letras[i])) {
        List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
        indexes.add(i);
        characterIndexes.put(letras[i], indexes);
    } else {
        characterIndexes.get(letras[i]).add(i);
    }
}

int contador = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < palabra.length(); k++) {
    char letraUsuario = Character.toLowerCase(sc.next().charAt(0));
    if (characterIndexes.containsKey(letraUsuario)) {
        for (int i : characterIndexes.get(letraUsuario)) {
            oculto[i] = letraUsuario;
        }
    } else {
        contador++;
    }
    for (char letra : oculto) {
        System.out.print(letra);
    }
    System.out.println();
    if (contador == 7) {
        break;
    }
}
sc.close();
```